# Not able to Query Data Needed based on an initial action

Tags: amazon-redshift

So I think the best way to go about this is to spell it all out, I tried many queries and failed so I turn to you wonderful people who have been doing this much longer. The data I am pulling from has 4 columns Order_num (stores the order number), Order_status_username (user Name), Order_Status_text (gives the message sent), and Order_Status_Time (time of message sent). So I need two things, first I need the results of this query:

```
Select count(distinct order_num ) as Total
From pos.order_status 
Where order_num in (Select order_num From pos.order_status Where order_status_username = 'stanleyb' and trunc(order_status_added) = '2020-10-01' and order_status_text ilike 'Sent to florist%')

Union 

Select count(distinct order_num) as Stayed
From pos.order_status 
where order_status_text Ilike '%to [Delivered]' and 
order_num in (Select order_num From pos.order_status Where order_status_username = 'stanley' and trunc(order_status_added) = '2020-10-01' and order_status_text ilike 'Sent to florist%')
```

Which provides the total number of orders he sent manually. Now I need the number of orders that that Stanley sent out that got a specific message after he sent out the order. the data has a new row for each time that order has data sent back and forth between us and our vendors. I tried using:

```
Select count(distinct order_num) as Stayed
From pos.order_status 
where order_status_text Ilike '%to [Delivered]' and 
order_num in (Select order_num From pos.order_status Where order_status_username = 'stanleyb' and trunc(order_status_added) = '2020-10-01' and order_status_text ilike 'Sent to florist%')
```

But this does not allow for me to make so the statuses it shows that are related by order number, were sent after Stanley sent his message. I tried joining, I think I am missing something. Union kind of worked but still had an issue with making sure it only sent data after the event of Stanley sending the message that included 'Sent to florist%'. If you can provide any insight, still learning.

Comment: Man this makes me feel like Redshift scared everyone away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all of Stanly's records and join them on `pos.order_status` to get the records which:

- have the same `order_num`
- occur after his message
- have the desired text.

I've used verbose table aliases to try to make the logic clearer.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT after_stanlys_message.order_num)
FROM
  pos.order_status stanlys_message
  JOIN pos.order_status after_stanlys_message ON
    after_stanlys_message.order_num = stanlys_message.order_num
    AND after_stanlys_message.order_status_time > stanlys_message.order_status_time
    AND after_stanlys_message.order_status_text ILIKE '%to [Delivered]'
WHERE
  stanlys_message.order_status_username = 'stanleyb'
  AND TRUNC(stanlys_message.order_status_added) = '2020-10-01'
  AND stanlys_message.order_status_text ILIKE 'Sent to florist%'
```

Comment: Winner, winner, chicken dinner. Thank you. It is funny, I have the base to come up with something like this, but I tend to over complicate it.